# Calling Objective C function from UIWebView using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, ajax, uiwebview

I found online a tutorial where it says that ObjectiveC code can be called from a WebView using the following Javascript code

```
var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
iframe.setAttribute("src", "js-frame:myObjectiveCFunction");
document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
iframe = null;
```

Then from ObjectiveC I must implement UIWebViewDelegate to receive the     shouldStartLoadWithRequest. 
I tried this code and it worked; however, I was wondering if the same functionality could be implemented using an AJAX call instead of using an IFrame.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done if you change window.location with JS. it will invoke the delegate function you're using.

You may also use links on your page to execute an obj-c function using the same delegate method.

If you're planning to do a special call using AJAX, please explain it more.